Android TV orientation
Currently I have a TV app that worked fine in multiple orientation modes, however with the latest OS it doesn't seem to work as expected in portrait mode.
It appears that there is a lock on the landscape mode and
requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
doesn't do the trick anymore.
My question is, is there a way to override this and make it work as it used to?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
